# Can "without" be used in the same way as "with" to express the opposite meaning?

Tags: prepositions

I found the sentence below on one of my dictionaries.

> I sleep with the window open.

Can this sentence be rewritten as follows?

> I sleep without the window closed.

Comment: It would sound very odd. However, if the window was already open when you went to bed, you could say "I went to sleep without closing the window."